# Switching between activities raises Thread error

Tags: java, android, sdk

I make an app with two windows, when I go from main window to the preferences one everything is fine, but when I try to return back to main activity app crashes with Thread already started error.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

}
// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Update:
Here is the log from LogCat (I am using Eclipse):

```
09-30 11:59:17.348: D/AndroidRuntime(2917): Shutting down VM
09-30 11:59:17.348: W/dalvikvm(2917): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa7210)
09-30 11:59:17.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 11:59:17.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
09-30 11:59:17.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
09-30 11:59:17.368: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):     at com.examples.todolist.GameView$1.surfaceCreated(GameView.java:45)
```

The ManiFest file (activity from it):

```
<application

    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service 
        android:name="MusicService"
        android:enabled="true">

    </service>
    <activity

        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="PreferencesActivity"></activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
```

In my project I have MainActivity.java - which is main window, PreferencesActivity.java - which is preferences window, GameView.java - which is responsible for drawing stuff and GameManager.java - which controls FPS. In game view I have main, onDraw and onTouch events.
Here is main from GameView:

```
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gameLoopThread = new GameManager(this);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    gameLoopThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            gameLoopThread.start();
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
        }
    });
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.wall_sprite);
}
```

Here is a gameManager.java, since I figured out that it is something to do with run. I still trying to figure out how to make thread (or screen?) destroyed and then make it again.

public class GameManager extends Thread {

```
static final long FPS = 30;

private GameView view;

private boolean running = false;

// class constructor
public GameManager(GameView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    running = run;
}

public void run() {
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while (running) {
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire stack trace?

Comment: Please post your error in question.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli What do you mean by entire stack trace

Comment: Well originally there was no stack trace from logcat. Anyways, looks like you have a thread starting in your GameView class' onSurfaceCreated(). Not sure from the trace if the thread is an adhoc thread your class creates or the thread created for the surface (I assume it is not the surface thread since it wouldn't root the stack there). But depending on how your Manifest is set up, I think you might be recycling an instance of an Activity. In which case you might be starting a thread twice. Even with the new task (starting the new task on back sounds weird to me).

Comment: @GregGiacovelli I added GameView, which doesnt have onSurfaceCreated method as well as manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the deal, surfaceCreated() seems to hold a thread, and that thread can only be started once and only once. That is the immediate issue.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
            // This is unsafe
            gameLoopThread.start();
}
```

Without knowing the entire design of your app there are a few ways this can be triggered multiple times.

A Surface can be created, destroyed and then a new surface can be created. In this case, the GameView would have the same thread reference and try to start it again. So you have Activity-A with SurfaceView. Creates Surface, then you start another activity, your surface view will probably be destroyed around the time of the onPause(). You finish your Preferences and come back to your activity, onResume() gets called and your surface will be recreated ... firing twice. This is all assuming that your app goes something like this:
Activity -> PreferencesActivity -> original Activity.

You seem to start another task so I am unsure why you do that, but the old activity is still on the backstack, so if it resumes, it will probably recreate the surface.

Not sure what GameManager is required for but it looks like a run loop of some sort. You can either make sure it isn't started if it already is. Or if there is a case where there may be desired separate GameManager instances, you could keep track of multiple instances and make sure not to start them again.

Comment: You are right, if I comment out gameLoopThread.start(), then the program doesn't crash on switching back to original Activity. But how do I make process being destroyed, since i redraw main window, maybe it will be good idea to destroy it when I switch to Prefernces?

Comment: Well you would have to finish the activity every time you leave it. And then would have to restart it before going back to it. I think managing the state of whether or not your activity and thread are already running is much easier to maintain.

Comment: I think now it would be easier to figure out, since I posted almost full program

Comment: The problem is still the same, you CANNOT under any circumstances call start() on the same instance of a Thread object more than once.